# YII: What is wrong with my condition? (if statement)

Tags: php, if-statement, yii

I have the following code, and both images show up if they are outside of the condition, but the moment I put them inside the condition they don't work. What am I doing wrong? I'm using the YII framework...

```
<?php if ($avatar) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" class="avatar" alt="" />
<?php } else { ?>
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/images/no-image.jpg" width="186px" class="avatar" alt="" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: what is value of `$avatar` ?

Answer (score 1):

`if ($avatar)` asks if $avatar is defined (ie exists).

If $avatar is defined `<img src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" class="avatar" alt="" />`  is displayed.

If $avatar is NOT defined you get a warning `Notice: Undefined variable: avatar`

The following code uses  PHP Function [isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) (As noted by Cole Johnson)

```
<?php 
$flag = 0;
//Try commenting out line below to illustrate
$avatar =1;
if (isset($avatar)) {
$flag =1;
}
if ($flag == 1){
 ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" class="avatar" alt="" />
<?php } 
else { ?>
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme; ?>/images/no-image.jpg" width="186px" class="avatar" alt="" />
<?php 
} ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply... but that code doesn't work :(  Now the avatar doesn't show either...

Comment: @CK-idiot `$avatar =1;` is only for test purposes. As I don't have your full code this was put in to illustrate.The code works as is showing first condition  and if you comment out `$avatar =1;` the second condition shows. Obviously you will need to modify it to meet your own requirements.

Comment: Put something in alt, chech if code is entering your if condition or not, if its entering then take image name into $avatar, echo it outside the if condition then inside the if condition and done, you will now the problem and it will get resolved. thanks.